# How can I recreate the layout in the example Using TailwindCSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to let rows intercalate each other, as represented below:

[image]

The problem is at the moment I can't intercalate the rows, so I end up having a layout that looks like this:

[image]

Or a more real example of what I have:

[image]

I tried a lot of ways, including Grid Auto Flow, Inline Grid and also making the child Inline Block but nothing seem to work. From what I inspected each column is as big in height as the one in right, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a solution to achieve the desired output using grid layout.

A possible way to do it would be using `w-1/2` to set the width of both columns and to `absolute`ly position the second column at the top right corner of the parent. Please check the code snippet below for example.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="relative h-full w-full">
  <div class="w-1/2">
    <div class="w-full h-20 bg-blue-400"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-10 bg-yellow-400"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-36 bg-red-400"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute right-0 top-0 w-1/2"> 
    <div class="w-full h-40 bg-green-400"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-36 bg-indigo-400"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```